# finding the parent index in an interval heap (stored on an array) given a child index

Tags: data-structures, arrays, heaps

an interval heap is a binary tree stored on an array where the size of each node is 2.

i would like to be able to find the index of a parent and find one of the child indices given the index of a node.

an example of an interval trees indices would be:

```
         [0,1]

    [2,3]     [4,5]

[6,7][8,9][10,11][12,13]
```

or

```
         [1,2]

    [3,4]     [5,6]

[7,8][9,10][11,12][13,14]
```

Comment: (Does "the" mapping of binary tree nodes to array indices depend on the interpretation of the tree? I would expect the customary $*/2\pm1$.)

Comment: @greybeard as far as i'm aware, it adds +1 or -1 into places.
the solution to this question is probably really obvious, but i can't tell anymore.